# How to highlight current week when loading datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to highlight current week when loading datepicker using jQuery?

For example today is Thursday, it will highlight Monday till Friday when load the datepicker.

Similar : http://jsfiddle.net/W5GMg/222/, but i want to select the week on Monday instead of + number of days.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line of code in your Fiddle here:

```
SVG.Weekpicker._dates = 
   SVG.Weekpicker.GetWeek(new Date(_currentDate.getFullYear(),
                                   _currentDate.getMonth(),
                                   _currentDate.getDate()));
```

You have to change `_currentDate.getDate()` to the day of the month that is the Monday of the week you want to highlight.

[This example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzQ9v/1/) highlights the week starting Monday, August 27.